# bcc not working in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a small mail app using google script. Everything is working fine but bcc field. The email gets sent to target but no bcc is sent. When I replace it by cc, things start working normally.

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:"email@example.com", 
    subject: "subject", 
    bcc: "email2@example.com",
    htmlBody: body,
    name: 'sample',
    attachments: [iCard.getAs(MimeType.PDF), samplePaper.getAs(MimeType.PDF), instruction.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
  })
```

Comment: I tested your code with real email addresses, it works as intended. You may be confused because bcc: is not shown in the "Sent Mail" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the example given here: [mailapp-bcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703009/gmail-app-script-add-bcc-from-spreadsheet)

You have to pass the 'bcc' field as part of a javascript object parameter to mailapp.

Comment: Need to fix you link. Not knowing what it has, [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)) states: bcc - String - a comma-separated list of email addresses to BCC

Comment: The code sample in the question has bcc field as a part of object parameter. What is your point?